# Freya 0.3.2 New wallpaper package updated but no new wallpapers show up

Tags: wallpaper

I've just received an wallpaper package from Software Updater. I updated it but no new wallpapers show up in Setting->Desktop->Wallpaper.

Where are the new wallpapers saved? or
How can I make these new wallpaper appear in Setting->Desktop->Wallpaper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wallpapers are stored in `/usr/share/backgrounds`. It's likely that this update didn't actually change or add wallpapers, but rather updated copyright information or stuff like that.

Comment: There're two new revisions by Daniel Foré the past 2016-01-21 with the numbers 45 & 46, deleting some wallpapers and add new one. For more information:

https://code.launchpad.net/~elementary-design/elementaryos/elementary-wallpapers